# issue of playing memory game by using Javascript, CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I meet some difficulties of playing memory games. The first step of this task is to enable the "play" button only if I entered the same name as the Placeholder. (I have set the placeholder as "Lianzheng"). This issue has been addressed. When I enter "Lianzheng" in the form, the button will be enabled. The second step is that after I click on the "play" button, The game should be displayed and played. Also, the game should not appear before I click on the "play" button.

My problem is that when I click on the "play" button, there is no game appearing, so there must be something wrong. Where is the issue?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="type/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "main.css" />
    <title>HTML 5</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form name="play">
        <div class="play">
            <p>Name: 
                <br/>
                <input type= "text" placeholder="Lianzheng" id= "inputField" onkeyup="myFunction()" onkeydown="myFunction()">
                <br/>
                <p><input type="button" name="play" disabled="disabled" id="play" value="play" onclick="play()">
                </p>
            </div>

        </form>

        <script>
            function myFunction() { //check whether the input value is equal to the placeholder value
                var placeholderValue = document.getElementById("inputField").placeholder;
                var valueEntered = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
                if(placeholderValue == valueEntered){
                    document.getElementById("play").removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
                else{
                    if(!document.getElementById("play").hasAttribute("disabled")){
                        document.getElementById("play").setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
                    }

                }

            }
            setInterval(function(){  // set the interval
             var placeholderValue document.getElementById("inputField").placeholder;
             var valueEntered = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
             if(placeholderValue == valueEntered){
                document.getElementById("play").removeAttribute("disabled");
            }
            else{
                if(!document.getElementById("play").hasAttribute("disabled")){
                 document.getElementById("play").setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
             }

         }
     },1000);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
    var memory_array = ['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','G','G','H','H','I','I','J','J','K','K','L','L'];
    var memory_values = [];
    var memory_tile_ids = [];
    var tiles_flipped = 0;
    Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function(){
        var i = this.length, j, temp;
        while(--i > 0){
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            temp = this[j]; 
            this[j] = this[i];
            this[i] = temp;
        }
    }

function play(){
    tiles_flipped = 0;
    var output = '';
    memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
    for(var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++){
        output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+memory_array[i]+'\')"></div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
}
function memoryFlipTile(tile,val){
    if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2){
        tile.style.background = '#FFF';
        tile.innerHTML = '<img src="' +val + '.png"/>';
        if(memory_values.length == 0){
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        } else if(memory_values.length == 1){
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
            if(memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]){
                tiles_flipped += 2;
                memory_values = [];
                memory_tile_ids = [];
                if(tiles_flipped == memory_array.length){
                    alert("Board cleared... generating new board");
                    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                    newBoard();
                }
            } else {
                function flip2Back(){
                    var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
                    var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
                    tile_1.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
                    tile_1.innerHTML = '<img src="' + val + '.png"/>';
                    tile_2.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
                    tile_2.innerHTML = '<img src="' + val + '.png"/>';
                    memory_values = [];
                    memory_tile_ids = [];
                }
                setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
form {
    border-color: #A3BDDD;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 3in;
    height: 2in;
    background-color: #DCE6F2;
}

div#memory_board{
    background:#CCC;
    border:#999 1px solid;
    width:800px;
    height:540px;
    padding:24px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

div#memory_board > div{
    background: url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    border:#000 1px solid;
    width:71px;
    height:71px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:64px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: have you seen your javascript console? Any error raised?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the errors. There is no error raised. It's just not working when I click on the "play" button

Comment: Keep breakpoint in developer tools of your favorite browser and check..

Comment: Why do you have duplicated code of `function myFunction` and `setInterval(function(){`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Try `onclick="play()"`

```
<input type="submit" name="play" disabled="disabled" id="play" value="play" onclick="play()">
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my error. But it's still not working after modifying this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have several things going on here:

```
<input type="submit" name="play" disabled="disabled" id="play" value="play" onclick="play">
```

1)  You probably want to use a type="button" instead of type="submit".  You aren't really wanting to submit a form -- you just want something to happen when you click a button.

2) Why would you want the button disabled?

3) When calling a function you need to include the (..)'s.

This all boils down to replacing that line with:

```
<button id="play" value="play" onclick="play()">
```

Note: I did not look at your JavaScript to see if there are any errors there to get your game started, because you need to focus on getting the HTML correct first.

Comment: It's a requirement. Because the professor hoped to know if we know how to enabled the button after the input. So the initial status of the button will be disabled.

Comment: Gotcha.  In looking at your code, the play() function doesn't do anything other than set variables and an array up.  Perhaps it should call newBoard(..) -- otherwise your screen won't do anything at all.

Comment: I have modified. What does the (..)'s mean?

Comment: I just meant "parenthesis".

Comment: I still don't see where the play() function does anything to start a game.  It initializes variables, but never calls either newBoard() or memoryFlipTile(tile,val) ... so there is no code running in play() that should make the game visibly start on your screen.  It's a wild guess because I don't want to try and interpret your code, but I think you should potentially call newBoard() as the last line of your play() function.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to change to newBoard, but then I debug, it says that I have not definied newBoard